# SQL. Как найти комбинации 10 самых популярных тэгов?

Tags: sql

Используемые ссылки:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1658832
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyIkW.png
Полученный результат должен соответствовать результату на картинке.[image: Результат]

Comment: Сортировка + ограничение количества записей в выходном наборе. как это выглядит в коде - зависит от СУБД.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос более чётко. ЧТо такое комбинация? У вас в ответе пары, как они получились непонятно. Как определяется популярность.. Пока задачу можно интерпретировать кучей разных способов.